# dynamically insert script from 3rd-pty into HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on a clients automotive sales site and they have contracted with a 3rd Pty vendor  that has provided a script to be run on their Inventory Results and Details pages.

The Inventory Listings Results and Details pages are data driven dynamically pulling in vehicle data from a DB source.

What I am looking to do:

1. once the page loads insert this 3rd party code dynamically to the DIV container for each inventory listings and subsequently for each details page.

Here is the 3rd PTY code block that I am trying to insert dynamically to each vehicle listing:

```
<div class="lowPrice">
<a href="javascript:displayLoanInfo(vehicleVIN, SourceID);" id="lbl'+vehicleVIN+'"></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    GetLowestPayment('vehicleVIN', 'SourceID', "lbl'+vehicleVIN+'");

    function AssignLowestPayment(LowestPaymentValue, ClientLabelID) {
        if (LowestPaymentValue !== '') {
            document.getElementById(ClientLabelID).innerHTML = LowestPaymentValue;
        };
    };
</script>
```

I've setup a .JS file already to load in the client script via a $(getScript) function, and I know enough JQuery to be able to grab the data elements for each vehicle from the page and pass to the function (I belive I've done this correctly). However, I am stuck at the point where I need to insert the above code and have those variables holding requisite data elements passed to it correctly.

HERE is the code from my .JS file that I've written so far:

```
var loc = document.location;
var endrive = /inventory-results|inventory-details/.test(loc.pathname);
var SourceID = '10057', ChromeStyleID = '', vehicleZipCode='06473', mode = 'text',vehicleCondition = "",lresult,dresult;
if(/selectedcat\/new/.test(loc.pathname)){ vehicleCondition = "New";}
if(/selectedcat\/preowned/.test(loc.pathname)){ vehicleCondition = "Preowned";}
if(/inventory-results/.test(loc.pathname)){ divblock = '.piiResultsContainer'; lresult = true;cnt=-1}
if(/inventory-details/.test(loc.pathname)){ divblock = '#dt_vehicle_tbl';dresult= true;cnt=-1}



var vdata = [], vattr,vehicleVIN,vehicleStockNum,vehicleTransmission,vehicleOdometer,vehicleExtColor,vehiclePrice,vehicleStyle,vehiclePhoto,vehicleYear,vehicleMake,vehicleModel,vehicle;


if(endrive){
    $.getScript("http://www.velocitylogix.com/OfferLogix.js?width=960px&height=700&pack=false",function(){


    $(divblock).each(function(){

        if(lresult){
            vdata['vehiclePrice'] = $(this).find('#ulPricing li:first-child').text().trim();
            attrsearch = 'ul#att_listL li';
            SourceID = '10057';
        }
        if(dresult){
            vdata['vehiclePrice'] = $(this).find('#dt_vehicle_listing').find('ul#ulPricing li:first-child').text().trim();
            attrsearch = '#dt_vehicle_attribute ul#att_listL li';
            SourceID = '10057';
        }

        if(/MSRP/.test(vdata['vehiclePrice'])){ vdata['vehiclePrice'] = vdata['vehiclePrice'].replace("MSRP: ","");}
        if(/Selling Price/.test(vdata['vehiclePrice'])){ vdata['vehiclePrice'] = vdata['vehiclePrice'].replace("Selling Price: ","");}
        var tlist = $(this).find(attrsearch).each(function(){
            vattr =$(this).find('span').text();
            switch(vattr){
                case "VIN:":vdata['vehicleVin']=$(this).text().replace("VIN: ","");
                    break;
                case "Stock #:":vdata['vehicleStockNum']=$(this).text().replace("Stock #: ","");
                    break;

                case "Miles:":vdata['vehicleOdometer']=$(this).text().replace("Miles: ","");
                    break;
                default :
                    vdata['vehicleOdometer']= 0;
                    break;

            }
            vehiclePrice = vdata['vehiclePrice'];
            vehicleVIN = vdata['vehicleVin'];

        });
        cnt++;

        GetLowestPayment(vehicleVIN, SourceID, 'lbl' + vehicleVIN);

        function AssignLowestPayment(LowestPaymentValue, ClientLabelID) {
            if(LowestPaymentValue !== '') {
                document.getElementById(ClientLabelID).innerHTML = LowestPaymentValue;
            };
        };

        $(this).find('#ulPricing').append('<div style="max-width:260px; position:relative;z-index: auto;"><div id="din_'+cnt+'" style="white-space: nowrap;"></div><div class="lowPrice"><a href="javascript:displayLoanInfo(vehicleVIN, SourceID);" id="lbl'+vehicleVIN+'"></a></div></div>');
    });
});

}
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.